# Как правильно читать 2 файла параллельно ffmpeg c++?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

В Ютубе есть адаптивные форматы потока для аудио и видео, к сожалению они идут отдельно - отдельно аудио, отдельно видео.
Вытаскиваю 2 ссылки из ютуба по отдельности для видео (c itag 137, 1080p) и аудио (с itag 140, 128кбит/с).

Задача в следующем - читать через ffmpeg 2 этих фала параллельно.
Тоесть открыть каждый из них через функцию ниже и получить _format_context

```
avformat_open_input(&_format_context, url.GetBuffer(), NULL, NULL);
```

Перемещаться по файлам используя

```
av_read_frame(_format_context, &packet)
```

Дальше каждый _format_context (один для видео, другой для аудио) демультиплексировать, чтобы из одного контекста получать видео пакеты, а с другого контекста получать аудио пакеты

Дальше по плану их читать параллельно и воспроизводить, чтобы получить картинку на экране в 1080p и звук с качеством 128кбит/с

С темой только разбираюсь, поэтому приветствуются любые мудрые мысли, как это правильно реализовать...

Возможно может уже кто писал приложение для воспроизведения с Ютуба ролика в лучшем качестве и лучшем звуке и сможет поделиться структурированными мыслями. Или может более элегантным решением.
Спасибо!